# Display JSON in an HTML table and also add rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm looking for some psuedo-code to help me strategize this.  Here is what I'm trying to do:

I receive a JSON object with data that gets displayed in an HTML table.  Sometimes I use $each, sometimes I use a for loop.  Lots of ways to do that.  Let's say it's a table with columns for IP, MAC, and Name.  The JSON would look like this:

```
[{"mode": "ftp"},{"IP": "123.123"},{"MAC": "445566"}]
```

BUT, when I need to make a new row for the user to enter new data for IP, MAC and Name, I am repeating myself and making a function that creates a new row - it makes a new `<tr>` and `<td>` for each value, etc.  Since I have the table made up of static text fields and hidden inputs next to each (the toggle visibility when you click the "Edit" button), that's quite a bit of code to have twice in my application.

Is there an elegant way to do this in less code - I was thinking instead of displaying the data in the table outright, I make a function called addRow and it's parameters are the data for each row, then that way the page can call that function for each row initially, and again when I create a new row.

Some psuedo-code would be fine and I can fill in the blanks, I just want to know if there is another way of going about this or if there is a popular Javascript pattern for this kind of thing.

**Edit**: My request to use a third party plugin was not approved.  I know DataTables is great, but for this one, I'm on my own!

Comment: In my opinion, you should consider adding a row to the `json` object, and call again your function that draw the table. It will be cleaner since you constantly call a function to draw, and another to add (on the `json` object that you have saved before drawing).

Comment: can you change your JSON format to [{"mode": "ftp","IP": "123.123","MAC": "445566"}], have you looked at various data table plugins such as datatable.net?  It has a number of feature that make adding and editing  a row easy.

Comment: I prefer to code everything myself, that way it's quicker to make a change or a fix when something goes wrong on the page, rather than having to learn the edge cases of some plugin.  Also when we deliver this software, the customer prefers the only included library to be jQuery, so there is no additional learning curve for their own developers who will be maintaining it.

That being said, I have used DataTables in the past and it works great.  I didn't know it could also add rows and prepare data for a PUT.  I may do that.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for https://datatables.net (MIT License)

It's very "elegant" and quick, allowing you to initialize tables with json data. It has also easy to use addrow/inline editing features.

- Json Init:

https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

- AddRow:

https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

- Inline Editing:

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

Comment: I just feel like I'm relying too much on someone else's code when I use a big plugin rather than just doing it myself...but I didn't know it handled Ajax like that so I may give it a try.

Comment: I know what you mean, but sometimes reinventing the wheel is also not worth it. It depends on each case - you wouldn't want to rely on third party code for a large project, but for smaller solutions I'd say it's perfectly reasonable. Also, the MIT License makes this quite attractive

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track with your original idea of just creating an `addRow` function and calling that. But, bear in mind that you want to edit the DOM as litle as possible since each `append` or `insert` will typically result in a redraw...so, maybe instead of `addRow`, it would be better to us an `addRows` function that will allow you to append multiple rows at once. You cam call that initially with your rows of data to do a single append. Then, when you are adding only a single row, just edit your data so it's an array of length one. That is, pass it `[rowData]` (adding the brackets to make the outer layer an array of length one) and not just `rowData`.

That is,

```
  // Create the table element and add the headers.
  function createTableAddHeaders(){
    // however you want to do it.
  }

  // Each element of 'rowsToAppend' will be transformed into
  // a table row. Append rows is agnostic as to whether
  // the input rows already exist in the table. 
  // It will just keep appending the input to the table
  function appendRows(rowsToAppend){
    // code to append input 'rowsToAppend'to the tableElem 
  }

  // Example Call ----------------------------
  // This is the data we will use to create the original table
  var originalRows = [
    ["Row Number", "id1", "id2", "id3"], // Header
    ["Row 1", 1,2,3], // data
    ["Row 2", 4,5,6]  // data
  ];

  createTableAddHeaders();  // Create table
  appendRows(originalRows); // Append original data to the table


  // Now we have new data we want to append.
  var newRow = ["Row 3: New Row", 7, 8, 9];
  // Wrap it in a [] when calling appendRows so the
  // outer layer becomes an array of length one
  appendRows([newRow]);
```

Comment: I think I see what you mean.  Not sure about the rowData brackes outer layer array thing, can you expand on that?

Comment: [SpaceNinja](http://stackoverflow.com/users/757853/spaceninja) sure thing. I just added an example.